# Mongoid where query using count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, mongoid, where-clause, relation

I have the next models, using Mongoid:

```
class Album
  have_many :images
end

class Image
  belongs_to :album
end
```

I want to get only albums that have any images:

```
Album.all.select{ |a| a.images.count > 0 }
```

But it return an array and I need a Mongoid::Criteria. I tried using something like:

```
Album.where( "this.images.count > 0" )
```

and it always return 0 elements. ¿ How can I do it ?

Comment: I am not sure but this `Album.joins(:images)` should return an array of albums who has at least one image - to check on your side: I'm not that sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that is not an array, and it is a Proxy.
you can check the logs and see that moped is calling .count funcion for every album(2 in my case).

```
1.9.3-p194 :043 > Album.each { |a| a.images.count }
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=mongo_benchmark collection=albums selector={} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 fields=nil (0.7441ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=mongo_benchmark command={:count=>"images", :query=>{"album_id"=>"50e36dd17c71c110ff000001"}} (0.5209ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=mongo_benchmark command={:count=>"images", :query=>{"album_id"=>"50e36f8f7c71c110ff000004"}} (0.3800ms)
```

Also if you want to get the Criteria object you can do `album.images.scoped`

If you have lots of albums it will call count for ever one, which is not good. I would advise you to use a counter cache in this situation. you can use a branch that I have including counter cache to mongoid https://github.com/arthurnn/mongoid/tree/2215-counter_cache

Comment: Thank I didn't know about counter cache.